# Very odd compilation error with varargs

Tags: java, enums, compiler-errors

I am writing an enum for all the opcodes in the JVM. It isn't complete, and looks like this so far:

```
public enum Opcode {
    NOP(),
    ACONST_NULL(),
    ICONST_M1(),
    ICONST_0(),
    ICONST_1(),
    // a zillion more of these
    JSR_W();

    private Opcode(Class<? extends Argument> args...) {
    }
}
```

There is a compilation error on the line of the construction declaration:

> ')' expected

What is going on?

Comment: You don't need the empty `()` on your constants.

Comment: @PeterLawrey If I leave it out, does it attempt to call a constructor with no parameters?

Comment: Only if you have one, otherwise it calls the one you have with an empty array.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `...` notation goes on the parameter type not on the parameter name, like so

```
private Opcode(Class<? extends Argument>... args) {
}
```

For thoroughness, the [Java Language Specification states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1) that a method's parameter list has the following form

```
FormalParameterList:
    LastFormalParameter
    FormalParameters , LastFormalParameter
```

where `LastFormatParameter` has the form

```
LastFormalParameter:
    VariableModifiersopt Type... VariableDeclaratorId
    FormalParameter
```

The `...` comes after the parameter type declaration.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping with that bit of amnesia. I'll accept in 9 minutes.